# How to Convert United States State Plane coordinates to Latitude and Longitude in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How to Convert United States State Plane coordinates to Latitude and Longitude in Mathematica?

I'm converting Washington DC Northing and Easting (in feet) of a location to latitude and longitude
Here is the address:
316 PENNSYLVANIA AVENUE SE  20003

And here are the  coordinate:

X= 399901.19    Y= 135465.63

I know that I should be ND83 and my SPC Zone is MD-1900

I checked GeodesyData[] and I tried all these:
"NAD27", "NAD831986", "NAD83CORS93", "NAD83CORS94", "NAD83CORS96", \
"NAD83HARN" 
with GeoPosition[{399901, 135465, 0}, datum] but with no success.  I know in R I can use epsg:2804 or epsg:3559 but in Mathematica, I don't know which code to use, and none of these worked.

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Comment: you should ask on mathematica.stackexchange.com.  This sort of thing is often not well documented but someone may know.

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to answer it:

Our coordinates are in datum NAD83 for Maryland 1800.  Therefore, our datum string for Mathematica should be "SPCS83MD00"
Knowing the State and the code connected to to the state are crucial to build the datum string.  After SPCS83, one adds the state, in this case MD, and the last 2 digits of the four-digit code.

Hence, one can convert to (WGS84) or latitude and longitude as follows:

```
    LatitudeLongitude[GeoGridPosition[{399901., 135466.}, "SPCS83MD00"]]
```

One more thing:

If you want to find out the extension for SPCS83 or NAD 83 in Mathematica you just need to use, and start typing SPCS83 or NAD83 and it will give you the possible string containing the state and its codes (some states have more than 1 code)

```
  GeoProjectionData["SPCS83MD00"]
```